# Edit records on click in the front end temporarily - rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Actually I want to edit the respective records when Edit link is been clicked but for temporarily.

Right now when I clicked on the **Edit** link it takes me to http://localhost:3000/aslani361s/1/edit and asks me to update the record and the updated record is saved to database.

What I want is to do the same but on temporarily basis I want to change the records values in the front end in order to know the running balance and again go back to the normal statement with no modification in the records values in the database.

I want to do this because We have got customers sometimes they take half of their goods and rest half goods remain undelivered.So I want to know the balance amount payable by the respective customer after deducting that undelivered goods amount.

Right now I am just hiding the undelivered invoice with **hide**.

First I add a migration by typing this in your console:

```
rails g migration AddHiddenToAslani361s hidden:boolean
```

Opened the generated migration file and changed the following line:

```
add_column :aslani361s, :hidden, :boolean, :default => false
```

Saved the file und ran the migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then I added the hide method,

aslani361s_controller.rb

```
def hide
        @aslani361 = Aslani361.find(params[:id])
        @aslani361.hide
        flash[:notice] = 'Aslani361 was successfully hidden.'
        redirect_to aslani361s_url    
    end
```

_aslani361.html.erb

```
<tr   class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

    <td class="col-1"><%= aslani361.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></td>

    <td class="col-3"><%= span_with_possibly_red_color aslani361.description %></td>


    <td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(aslani361.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(aslani361.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(aslani361.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


    <% @balance += aslani361.amount.to_f - aslani361.discount.to_f - aslani361.paid.to_f %>

    <% color = @balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

    <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(@balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1"><%= link_to "Hide", controller: "aslani361s", action: "hide", id: aslani361, method: :put %></td>

</tr>
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @balance = 0 %>


<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        <div  class="table-responsive myTable">

            <table id = "kola" class="table listing text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="tr-head">
                        <td>Date</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Amount</td>
                        <td>Discount</td>
                        <td>Paid</td>
                        <td>Balance</td>
                        <td>Hide</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>                
                    <tbody>              
                        <%= render @aslani361s %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

aslani361.rb

```
scope :visible, -> { where(hidden: false) }
  # returns only visible xvaziri's

  def hide
    update_attribute(:hidden, true)
  end

 scope :hidden, -> { where(hidden: true) }
```

routes.rb

```
resources :aslani361s do 
        member do 
            get :hide
        end
    end
```

The above functionality is working fine as it is hiding the whole invoice with undelivered goods with running balance.

How do I get this working when part of goods are undelivered and part of goods are delivered, as I want to hide undelivered part from view and calculate the running balance.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't do this natively but you can use a gem like https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail to track changes in a model.

Or in your case just add `taken_goods` to your model in Rails.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like each record (or line_item) has a state such as delivered or undelivered.  You want to total up the ones that are undelivered.  Just change the state of the items in the list, don't edit the order itself.

You'll need to change this to a put

```
resources :aslani361s do 
    member do 
        put :hide
    end
end
```

In the index action

```
def index
    @aslani361s = Aslani361.visible
end
```

At the botttom of the table

```
<%= @aslani361s.sum(:amount) - @aslani361s.sum(:discount) - @aslani361s.sum(:paid) %>
```

Will calculate the total balance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I do have the records with delivered and undelivered but sometimes our delivery becomes in parts that is why I want to find out the running balance excluding some part of undelivered records.So if I can achieve this by changing the state how do I proceed?

Comment: Just add a state column to the line_item.  When you calculate the totals, use a scope to find all undelivered line_items and then sum their price.  Depending on what your order and line item models are - it would be something like `@order.line_items.undelivered.sum(:price)`

Comment: Thanks Sir, I have updated my post, please have a look, as I clearly mentioned what I have and what I want?

Comment: Added more that may help

Comment: Thanks again, Can't I edit the values of the records in the index view temporarily, for example if I have a invoice # 001 having the amount of 100,000 and discount of 20,000 so the balance will be 80,000 in which we delivered goods to customer 50,000 and rest 30,000 remain undelivered and I have to hide or remove temporarily from the view and exclude it in the running balance the only part which is undelivered but of the  same invoice.For your kind information, I have single invoice record in which I have to take care of both delivered and undelivered.Is it possible to handle?

Comment: Better we continue this in chat.